# How to use JavaScript to make a html file

Tags: javascript

so I'm making a test site for my online school and I wanted to try generate a new html file using a variable in javascript.
So basically the javascript variable is:

```
var test = "<h1>test</h1>"
```

and all i want to do is turn that into a html file using JavaScript

Comment: File or element? Is this within a browser or node.js? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileSaver.js
Try this simple script.

```
<html>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/filesaver.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="btn">create file</button>
</body>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
       var blob = new Blob(["<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
       saveAs(blob, "my_html_file.html");
})
</script>
</html>
```

This will create a file and download it. If you want to create a file and automatically place it in a file system you would need node. AFAIK it's not possible with plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try to using node application. like filesystem package. it will help you to create file. and u can store you're variable into that file.

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp